# Do processes in cgroups have to be set every boot? If so, how to persist them?

Tags: performance, limit, cgroups

I was reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40248/4193) to a question on setting limits for processes by using cgroups.  The sample given sets limits for a process (in the example, `sshd`).  In the answer, the PID of the process is set manually.  This would be unacceptable for my purposes, I would like that processes started from a given application to always have the limits set, no matter when they are started nor limited by how many such processes are started.

Perhaps it is unclear from the example how that would happen, so a clear explanation or link to one would also be welcome.  The example in the kernel cgroups.txt seems to use the same model as [already given above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40248/4193).

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is using `systemd` which may be responsible for your `sshd` anyway (depending on the distribution). You can easily configure the limits in the `sshd` unit file. `systemd` puts all services in separate cgroups anyway.

Without `systemd` the easiest solution is probably a modification to the `sshd` start script (pay attention that it's not overwritten by an update; it may be a good idea to copy it to a different name and disable the original script).

Comment: There is a troublesome app that limits would be great to clean up, that is not sshd.  It is just that sshd was used in the example.  Presumably, you can apply cgroups to any process.  A script might end up being the easiest solution.  It looked like cgroups would have been a good answer, though.

Comment: @casualunixer You just have to write a unit file for your app. You can configure is so that it is startet automatically on boot or just manually.

Comment: @laging, if you could give an example unit file in an answer, or pointer for documentation to one similarly, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @casualunixer It's exactly where one would expect it: `man systemd` leads to `man 5 systemd.unit` leads to `man 5 systemd.service`. On my system the SSH file is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service`.

Comment: Ah, given I do not have systemd installed, even though that is the topic of this answer, it was not immediately obvious.